# Why do Hive & HiveServer2 Require mapred.InputFormat?

Tags: java, hadoop, mapreduce, hive

I just want to make sure I'm not missing something.  I'm working on an `InputFormat` for Hive to deal with our specific hdfs-file-format.  I just realized that it needs to extend `mapred.InputFormat` instead of the `mapreduce.InputFormat`

Is this right?  Or am I missing something?  Can I use the `FileInputFormat` from the `mapreduce` package?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You will have to use `mapred.InputFormat` Hive has not fully migrated to the new package yet. Should you need/want to use `mapreduce.InputFormat` package for any reason, you can always wrap the `mapreduce.InputFormat`. In fact, that's what I did to get it interact with Hive but still leverage the `mapreduce` package.

**EDIT:** In order to interoperate between the two types of APIs, I abstracted the logic of reading the file records to another class and use it in both InputFormats.

Comment: Thanks @Pradeep.  I started doing that, I just felt like I was on the wrong path.  Have you ever had to turn mapred.JobConf into a mapreduce.TaskAttemptContext?  I'm really struggling with that, not sure from where I can get the job-id, task-id ,etc...

Comment: Answered my question here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28466554/hadoop-how-to-extract-a-taskid-from-mapred-jobconf?answertab=oldest#tab-top