# Hadoop - How to extract a taskId from mapred.JobConf?

Tags: java, hadoop, mapreduce, hive

Is it possible to create a valid `*mapreduce*.TaskAttemptID` from  `*mapred*.JobConf`?

**The background**

I need to write a `FileInputFormatAdapter` for an `ExistingFileInputFormat`.  The problem is that the Adapter needs to extend `mapred.InputFormat` and the Existing format extends `mapreduce.InputFormat`.

I need to build a `mapreduce.TaskAttemptContextImpl`, so that I can instantiate the `ExistingRecordReader`.  However, I can't create a valid `TaskId`...the taskId comes out as null.

So How can I get the taskId, jobId, etc from `mapred.JobConf`.

In particular in the Adapter's `getRecordReader` I need to do something like:

```
public org.apache.hadoop.mapred.RecordReader<NullWritable, MyWritable> getRecordReader(
        org.apache.hadoop.mapred.InputSplit split, JobConf job, Reporter reporter) throws IOException {

    SplitAdapter splitAdapter = (SplitAdapter) split;

    final Configuration conf = job;

    /*************************************************/
    //The problem is here, "mapred.task.id" is not in the conf
    /*************************************************/
    final TaskAttemptID taskId = TaskAttemptID.forName(conf.get("mapred.task.id"));

    final TaskAttemptContext context = new TaskAttemptContextImpl(conf, taskId);
    try {
        return new RecordReaderAdapter(new ExistingRecordReader(
                splitAdapter.getMapRedeuceSplit(),
                context));
    } catch (InterruptedException e) {
        throw new RuntimeException("Failed to create record-reader.", e);
    }
}
```

This code throws an exception:

```
Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
    at org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.task.TaskAttemptContextImpl.<init>(TaskAttemptContextImpl.java:44)
    at org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.task.TaskAttemptContextImpl.<init>(TaskAttemptContextImpl.java:39)
```

'super(conf, taskId.getJobID());' is throwing the exception, most likely because taskId is null.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found the answer by looking through `HiveHbaseTableInputFormat`.  Since my solution is targeted for hive, this works perfectly.

```
 TaskAttemptContext tac = ShimLoader.getHadoopShims().newTaskAttemptContext(
        job.getConfiguration(), reporter);
```